# dispatch async function in custom middleware in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-middleware

I am trying to create a custom middleware which dispatches `logout` action (async function) based on some condition in redux. As soon as action is dispatched, it throws error `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

store.js:

```
const handleAction = (store) => (next) => (action) => {
  const token = loadState(TOKEN);
  const { userAccount } = store.getState();
  if (token && userAccount.email) {
    const decodedJwt = jwt_decode(token);
    if (decodedJwt.exp < dayjs().unix()) {
      store.dispatch(logoutAction());
    }
  }
  return next(action);
};

export function configureStore(initState = {}) {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk,handleAction))
  );
  return store;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prevent the `logoutAction()` from causing the middleware to dispatch `logoutAction()` and so on...

```
if(action.type === 'your logoutAction type') return next(action);
```

Example:

```
const handleAction = (store) => (next) => (action) => {

  if(action.type === 'your logoutAction type') return next(action);
  
  const token = loadState(TOKEN);
  const { userAccount } = store.getState();
  if (token && userAccount.email) {
    const decodedJwt = jwt_decode(token);
    if (decodedJwt.exp < dayjs().unix()) {
      store.dispatch(logoutAction());
    }
  }
  return next(action);
};
```

You can also combine it with your existing condition:

```
const handleAction = (store) => (next) => (action) => {     
  const token = loadState(TOKEN);
  const { userAccount } = store.getState();
  if (action.type !== 'your logoutAction type' && 
      token && 
      userAccount.email) {
    const decodedJwt = jwt_decode(token);
    if (decodedJwt.exp < dayjs().unix()) {
      store.dispatch(logoutAction());
    }
  }
  return next(action);
};
```

Comment: Have you changed the "your logout action type" to the actual type?

Comment: oops.. sorry. my bad. It worked. Thank you